# Generalized linear combination of probability density functions

Tags: calculus, statistics

I am working with linear **non-unity** combinations of independent variables in the equation form of:
$$Y_i=\sum_{j=1}^N a_{ij} X_j ~~~~\forall~ a_{ij} \in \mathbb{R}, a_{ij}\neq 1$$
I am aware of the convolution solution for the simplified unity case:
$$Y=X_1+X_2 \rightarrow f_Y(z)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_{X_1}(x)f_{X_2}(z-x)dx$$
Since convolution is a linear operation, I could conceivably extend this solution to any number of unity weights.

My question is this, how do I handle the non-unity weighting factors? I have some sample plots showing how the solution obviously shifts. I'm using a normal distribution and an f-distribution. Below is the equation example showing the non-unity weighting factor.

$$Y=5\cdot f(x,dfn=5,dfd=18)+1\cdot \mathrm{norm}(x,\mu=0,\sigma=0.1)$$

For the record, I don't want a specific case solution (as in, don't solve the above). I am content with sets of integrals and related, since I know that there cannot be a single analytic form.

Thanks a lot for the help, and if I missed something on here that deals with the non-unity weights, please let me know. I have found several on unity weights, but those don't seem to help.

[image: bad relationship]
[image: good relationship]

By the way, this is my first question, LOL. :)

Comment: So you don't want to use the standard transformation of variables procedure as here: http://www.randomservices.org/random/dist/Transformations.html (See section on linear transformations)?  Instead you want a statement in terms of convolutions?

Comment: That's pretty much exactly what I was looking for, change of variables like that is totally fine. :) I don't why I didn't put it together, because I did find the change of variables (Jacobian) technique stuff in my own research.

Comment: Oh, great then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general procedure for determining the density of a transformed set of variables.  In the above situation, a linear transformation, it leads to a nice formula.  Let $f(x) = f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2)\cdots f_n(x_n)$ be the joint density of the $n$ independent random variables $X_i$.  Let $g(y)$ be the density of $Y = AX$ where $A$ is a matrix.  Then
$$g(y) = \frac{1}{|\det{A}|}f(A^{-1}y)$$

(see [Transformation of Variables](http://www.randomservices.org/random/dist/Transformations.html) for more details)